Croping a layer to match another one in QGIS
I am running an experiment to compare several layer of the same AOI however some layers are larger than the others. In order for my experiment to work, the layers should show the exact same AOI meaning I have to crop the larger layers to match the others.
In QGIS is there are way to select two layers and crop the larger one to match?

What is the nature of your layers? Raster layers, vector layers, or a mix?

Probably a simple but manual approach would be two clip operations followed by a Merge Vector Layers
ie: Layer A and Layer B
Clip Layer A to Layer B - Output 1
Clip Layer B to Layer A - Output 2
This will give you Layer A records that were larger than Layer B, will now match the geometry of layer B.
And Layer B records that were lager than A, now matching the geometry of B. Run a Merge Vector Layers and single result will ensue.
HOWEVER - This makes significant assumptions about your data and I think once you go down this path you will perhaps encounter some scenario's where its not going to be as simple as you think. I've shown a screen grab below where - Layer B is both larger and 'smaller' than Layer A - Its an exaggerated scenario but shows logically how it can be problematic.
If the AOI have attribute data, which - say for example, represent a suburb name, but the geometry is different, then there are other ways this problem can be resolved, so maybe an example and a screen capture of some scenario's would also help with this question.

